# python compare multiple dicts in list with multiple condition

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I want to make a new list of dict with comparison of bulk list of dicts. I have several conditions to compare between dicts. too much for loop and if condition make my code too slow. Plase let me know, any solution to make this quicker. thanks

```
[
    {
        document : '001',
        name: 'name1',
        qty : 1,
        item : 'item1',
        location : 'location1',
    },
    {
        document : '002',
        name: 'name2',
        qty : 1,
        item : 'item1',
        location : 'location1',
    },
    {
        document : '003',
        name: 'name3',
        qty : 2,
        item : 'item2',
        location : 'location2',
    },
    {
        document : '004',
        name: 'name4',
        qty : 1,
        item : 'item3',
        location : 'location3',
    },
    {
        document : '004',
        name: 'name4',
        qty : 1,
        item : 'item4',
        location : 'location3',
    },
    {
        document : '001',
        name: 'name1',
        qty : 1,
        item : 'item5',
        location : 'location2',
    },
]
```

Conditions

1. Single Item, Single Quentity
2. Single Item, Multiple Quentity
3. Multiple Item, Single Quentity
4. Multiple Item, Multiple Quentity
5. Multiple Location

below is what is want to get from the list above.

```
[
    [
        {
            condition : '05',
            document : '001',
            name: 'name1',
            qty : 1,
            item : 'item1',
            location : 'location1',
        },
        {
            condition : '05',
            document : '001',
            name: 'name1',
            qty : 1,
            item : 'item5',
            location : 'location2',
        },
    ],
    {
        condition : '01',
        document : '002',
        qty : 1,
        item : 'item1',
        name: 'name2',
        location : 'location1',
    },
    {
        condition : '02',
        document : '003',
        qty : 2,
        item : 'item2',
        name: 'name3',
        location : 'location2',
    },
    [
            condition : '03',
            document : '004',
            qty : 1,
            item : 'item3',
            name: 'name4',
            location : 'location3',
        },
        {
            condition : '03',
            document : '004',
            qty : 1,
            item : 'item4',
            name: 'name4',
            location : 'location3',
        },
    ]
]
```

```
newList = []

for row in rawList:
    tempList = []

    if 'condition' not in row:
        idx = [i for i,d in enumerate(rawList) if d["document"] == row['document']]

        if len(idx) > 1:
            is_multi_qty = max([rawList[i]['qty'] for i,d in enumerate(idx) if rawList[i]['qty'] > 0])
            is_multi_item = True if len(list(set([rawList[i]['item'] for i,d in enumerate(idx) if 'item' in rawList[i]]))) > 1 else False
            is_multi_location = True if len(list(set([rawList[i]['location'] for i,d in enumerate(idx) if 'location' in rawList[i]]))) > 1 else False

            for i in idx:
                if is_multi_location:
                    # condition5
                    rawList[i]['condition'] = '05'
                    tempList.append(rawList[i])
                    continue
                
                # condition2
                if (is_multi_qty > 1 and is_multi_item is not True):
                    rawList[i]['condition'] = '02'
                
                # condition3
                elif is_multi_qty == 1 and is_multi_item:
                    rawList[i]['condition'] = '03'

                # condition4
                elif is_multi_qty > 1 and is_multi_item:
                    rawList[i]['condition'] = '04'

                tempList.append(rawList[i])

        elif len(idx) == 1:
            # condition1
            row['condition'] = '01'
            tempList.append(row)
    
    if len(tempList) > 0:
        newList.append(tempList)
```

Comment: You would better change your dict to a pandas dataframe, manipulate it, and resave it as a dict.

Comment: "Multiple Location" how you checking this confition?

Comment: Sorry, I just change the key in the condition of is_multi_location